# How to solve a linear congruence $8n+9\equiv 0\pmod{\!1163}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Problem :

Solve in $\mathbb N$ :

$8n+9\equiv 0\pmod{1163}$

The mathematics give me : $n=435+1163k$ , $k\in\mathbb N$

$1163$ is a prime number

$8n\equiv -9\pmod{1163}$

$8n\equiv 1154\pmod{1163}$

I don't know any ideas to complete my work ?

I have to see your hints

Comment: or multiply by $8^{1161} \equiv 727\pmod {1163}$

Comment: Related to [OP's earlier question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3386999/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different method:

Let, $$\frac{8n+9}{1163}=m \in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$$

$$\begin{align}n=\frac{1163m-9}{8} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}} \Rightarrow\frac{(145\times8+3)m-8-1}{8} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}}  \Rightarrow \frac{3m-1}{8} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}} \Rightarrow \frac{8k+1}{3} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}} \Rightarrow \frac{9k+1-k}{3} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}} \Rightarrow \frac{k-1}{3} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}} \Rightarrow k=3z+1 \end {align}$$

$$m=\frac {8(3z+1)+1}{3}=8z+3$$
where,

$$\frac{3m-1}{8}=k \in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$$
$$\frac{k-1}{3}=z \in\mathbb{N_0}$$

Finally, we get

> $$n=\frac{1163m-9}{8}=\frac{1163(8z+3)-9}{8}=1163z+435$$ where $$z \in\mathbb{N_0}$$

Comment: Can you explain this ?? How $\frac{3m-1}{8} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}} \Rightarrow \frac{8n+1}{3}$

Comment: @EllenEllen I edited the answer.

Comment: I see but I ask how you move from $\frac{3m-1}{8}$ to $\frac{8n+1}{3}$ any substation ??

Comment: @EllenEllen I fixed the substitutions.

Comment: @EllenEllen If you dont understand my answer, please make a comment again.

Comment: @EllenEllen I explain this idea further in the final section on **Inverse Reciprocity** in my answer (see also the linked post there). It is equivalent to using two steps of the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @BillDubuque I didn't know either. I just learned. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @Elvin It is fully explained there. If you have any questions please feel welcome to post them in comments. Kudos for discovering it on your own!

Comment: @BillDubuque We are glad that there are people like you. We learn from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain how you got $\frac{1 - k}{3}$ to $\frac{k-1}{3}$?

Answer (score 6):

$$8n\equiv 1154\;(mod \;1163)$$ $$\Rightarrow 4n\equiv577\; (mod \;1163) $$ $$\Rightarrow 4n\equiv-586\; (mod \;1163) $$ $$\Rightarrow 2n\equiv-293\; (mod \;1163) $$ $$\Rightarrow 2n\equiv870\; (mod \;1163) $$ $$\Rightarrow n\equiv435\; (mod \;1163) $$

Comment: Thank you very much sir @lessili , but $x\equiv a\pmod{b}$ then $\frac{x}{n}\equiv  \frac{a}{n}\pmod{b}$ ? Always ?

Comment: Nice use of the oddness of the modulo. Do not be afraid of using `\iff` since $\gcd(2,1163)=1$ division by $2$ is ok (it would be nice you write it though).

Comment: Not always just in this case because 1163 is odd so you can divide by 2 as much as you want.

Comment: OK @lessili thanks again!

Comment: @Ellen I explain the idea behind this method in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Six ways** to compute $\!\bmod 1163\!:\ n\equiv \dfrac{-9}8\equiv -9 \cdot 8^{-1},\,$ the unique root of $\,8n\equiv -9$.

---

$\!\!\bmod 1163\!:\,\ n\equiv 3\left[\dfrac{-3}8\right] \equiv 3\left[\dfrac{1160}8\right]\equiv 3[145]\equiv 435\ $ by twiddling or Reciprocity below.

---

[Inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) is essentially the key idea behind lone student's and J.W.T's answer, viz.

$\!\!\bmod 1163\!:\,\ n \equiv \dfrac{-9}8\equiv \dfrac{-9+1163\color{#c00}k}8.\ $ To make the quotient *exact* we need $\,k\,$ such that

$\!\!\bmod 8\!:\,\ 0\equiv -9\!+\!1163k\equiv -9\!+\!3k\!\iff\! \color{#c00}{k\equiv 3},\ $ so $\ n \equiv \dfrac{-9\!+\!1163(\color{#c00}3)}8\equiv 435\pmod{\!1163}$

This idea is also (implicitly) used in the first method above, i.e.  $\,1163\equiv \color{#0a0}3\pmod{\!8}\,$ so clearly adding $1163$ to the numerator $\color{#0a0}{-3}$ makes the numerator divisible by $\,8,\,$ i.e. $\,\color{#c00}{k=1}\,$ works here (it is $\,1/3\,$ of the above $\,\color{#c00}{k=3}\,$ since there we factored out $\,3\,$ from the numerator $-9).\,$ In cases like this where small solutions exist for $\,k\,$ often we can "see" them quickly without explicitly solving the above linear congruence (e.g. by testing small values $\,k\equiv \pm1,\pm2\,$ etc, i.e. "**twiddle**" the numerator by adding small multiples of the modulus then testing if this yields an exact quotient). This is essentially an optimization of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (when it takes two steps).

---

$\!\!\bmod 1163\!:\,\ \dfrac{1}{4}\equiv\dfrac{1164}4\equiv 291\overset{\times\,\large\frac{\!-1}2}\Longrightarrow\: \dfrac{\!\!-1}8\equiv\dfrac{-291}2$ $\equiv\dfrac{872}{2}\equiv 436;\, $ subtract $\,1\,$ to get $\ \dfrac{\!-9}8$

---

As above & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326318/242) the freedom to choose  $\rm\color{#c00}{even}$ residue reps $\!\bmod\!$ odds makes **division by 2** easy:

$\bmod 1163\!:\,\ n\equiv \dfrac{-9}{8} \equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{-1172}}8\equiv \dfrac{-293}2\equiv\dfrac{\color{#c00}{870}}2\equiv 435.\ $ Or, similar to lesseli's answer

$\bmod 1163\!:\,\ n\equiv \dfrac{-9}{8}\ \equiv\ \dfrac{\color{#c00}{1154}}8\ \equiv\ \dfrac{577}4\equiv\dfrac{\color{#c00}{1740}}4\equiv435$.

The *key idea* is: if the modulus $m$ is odd then $\,2\mid a\,$ or $\,2\mid \color{#c00}{a\!\pm\!m},\,$ so we can quickly divide by $\,2\,$ by choosing the $\rm\color{#c00}{rep}$ that is *even*. Iterating that we can easily divide by all powers of $\,2\,$ (e.g $\,8\,$ above). This is the idea in lessili's answer, and the 2nd way above. More generally, see below.

---

$\!\!\bmod 1163\!:\ {-}n\equiv \dfrac{9}{8}\equiv \dfrac{145\cdot 9}{145\cdot 8}\equiv\dfrac{142}{-3}\equiv\dfrac{142\!+\!1163}{-3}\equiv -435\ $  by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

---

By the [*fractional* extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242), and associated [equational form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242)

$\qquad\quad \begin{align}  \bmod 1163\!:\ \ \dfrac{0}{1163}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\color{#c00}{\dfrac{-9}8}\!&\,\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\color{#0a0}{\dfrac{142}3}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\color{#90f}{\dfrac{435}1}\\[.7em]
 \text{said equationally}\ \ \ \ 
 [\![1]\!]\ \ \ \   1163\, x&\,\equiv\ \ \ 0\    \\
[\![2]\!] \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \color{#c00}{8\,x}&\ \color{#c00}{ \equiv -9}\!\!\!\\
[\![1]\!]-145\,[\![2]\!] \rightarrow [\![3]\!]\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \color{#0a0}{3\,x} &\ \color{#0a0}{\equiv\ \ 142}\   \\
[\![2]\!]\ \ -\ \ 3\,[\![3]\!] \rightarrow [\![4]\!]\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \color{#90f}{{-1}\,x}&\ \color{#90f}{ \equiv -435}  
\end{align}$

---

We can also use Newton's method (Hensel lifting) to lift inverses to higher powers, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3540538/242)

For more worked examples, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) for $5$ ways to compute $\,33/9\pmod{\!43}$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) for general theory and algorithms to solve a linear congruence $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\! n}$

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Comment: Did you mean $x\equiv\color{red}-\dfrac98\equiv435$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Updated sign to get OP"s problem.

Comment: @BillDubuque very difficult way ?? How or where I can learn it ??

Comment: @EllenEllen Which way?

Comment: I see you always use $\equiv \frac{a}{b}$ I never see it ??

Comment: @Ellen I added a simpler way by factoring out $\,3.\,$ Above $\,a/b\,$ means $\,ab^{-1},\,$ Modular fractions work just like normal fractions as long as you restrict to denominators *coprime* to the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

$8n\equiv1154\equiv2317\equiv\color{red}{3480}\bmod1163$.

Can you solve it now?

Comment: Thanks sir @J.W.Tanner

Answer (score 1):

If you are a *one trick pony* you can get the answer
using the (not always useful) shortcut found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3914190/432081):

$\; 8n \equiv -9\pmod{1163} \; \text{ iff }$
$\; 8n \equiv 1154\pmod{1163} \; \text{ iff }$
$\; 4n \equiv 577\pmod{1163}$

And since $4 \mid 1164$, the solution is

$\quad x = \Large(\frac{1164}{4}) \normalsize (577) = (291)(577) = 167907 \equiv 435 \pmod{1163}$

Of course a better trick is the one given by Laassila souhayl ($+1$).