# Prove that : $\frac{2k^{7}+1}{3k^{3}+2} \operatorname{reducible}\implies k\equiv 435\pmod{1163}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Question**:

> Define $\Omega =\frac{2k^{7}+1}{3k^{3}+2},k\in\mathbb{N}$.
> Prove that :
> $$\Omega \operatorname{reducible}\implies k\equiv 435\pmod{1163}$$

---

My try as follows:

Let $d=\gcd(2k^{7}+1,3k^{3}+2)$

So : $d$ divide $2k^{7}+1$ and $3k^{3}+2$ this mean :

$d$ divide

$$3(2k^{7}+1)-2k^{4}(3k^{3}+2)=3-4k^{4}$$

Then $d$ divide

$4k(3k^{3}+2)+3(3-4k^{2})=8k+9$$

How do I complete it? And where am I atop?

Comment: Doubtful. For $k=0,1$, the fraction is irreducible. Didn't you mean $k\not\equiv 435 \pmod {1163}$ ?

Comment: $k=2$ gives 257/26, which is irreducible.

Comment: @GreginGre , Almagest I'm very sorry I edited now !!

Comment: I added an answer that uses only very simple mental arithmetic.

Comment: In your question 2 months ago [I gave](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) for $6$ ways to compute $\dfrac{-9}8\pmod{\!1163}\ \ $

Comment: Hmm, I see you also asked the same question 3 months ago. Please don't duplicate your questions.

Comment: If you have questions about the prior answers you should ask them in comments there. If you don't get a satisfactory answer then you can ask a new more specific question explaining why the older answers don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your last step, we have,
$$d\Big\vert 8(3k^3+2)-3k^2(8k+9)$$
$$\implies d\Big\vert16-27k^2$$
$$\implies d\Big\vert27k(8k+9)+8(16-27k^2)$$
$$\implies d\Big\vert243k+128$$
$$\implies d\Big\vert243(8k+9)-8(243k+128)$$
$$\implies d\Big\vert1163$$
Now, $1163$ is a prime number, and for $\Omega$ to be reducible, $d>1$. Hence, 
$$d=1163$$
$$\implies 1163\Big\vert 8k+9-3\times1163$$
$$\implies 1163\Big\vert8(k-435)$$
Since $1163$ and $8$ are coprime, we are done.

Comment: very beautiful solution thanks! 

Comment: @EllenEllen, Thank You comments are deprecated by stackexchange (we appreciate the sentiment, though). You can upvote this answer to show your approval and click on the check mark to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: of course , glad you like it 

Comment: Use `\mid` instead of `\Big\vert` to get the right spacing

Answer (score 1):

More systematically:

The extended Euclidean algorithm for gcd [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialExtendedGCD%5B2+k%5E7+%2B+1%2C+3+k%5E3+%2B+2%2C+k%5D)
$$
1163 = A(2 k^7 + 1)+B(3 k^3 + 2)
$$
for some $A,B$ not relevant here.

Let $d=\gcd(2 k^7 + 1,3 k^3 + 2)$. Then $d$ divides $1163$.
If fraction is reducible, then $d>1$ and so $d=1163$ because $1163$ is prime.

Now, Euclidean division [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialQuotientRemainder%5B2+k%5E7+%2B+1%2C+3+k%5E3+%2B+2%2C+k%5D)
$$
9(2 k^7 + 1) = (6 k^4 - 4 k)(3 k^3 + 2) + (8 k + 9)
$$
Therefore, $d=1163$ divides $8 k + 9$. This is equivalent to $k\equiv 435\bmod{1163}$.

Indeed, to solve $8n+9\equiv 0\bmod{1163}$, find the inverse of $8$ mod $1163$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm. You'll get $727$. Then $n \equiv 727\cdot (-9) \equiv 435 \bmod{1163}$.

Comment: $8n+9\equiv 0\pmod{1163}$ then $8n\equiv 1154\pmod{1163}$ how I find value of $n$ ?

Comment: @EllenEllen, see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\bmod d = (3k^3\!+\!2,2k^7\!+\!1)\!:\,\ k^3 \equiv -\frac{2}3,\ k^7\equiv -\frac{1}2,\,$ so $\,(-\frac{2}3)^7\equiv k^{21}\equiv (-\frac{1}2)^3,\,$ so $\,0\equiv 3^7-2^{10}\equiv 1163.\,$  Thus $\,k \equiv k^7/(k^3)^3\equiv (-1/2)/(4/9)\equiv -9/8,\, $ and

$\!\!\bmod 1163\!:\,\  3\left[\dfrac{-3}8\right] \equiv 3\left[\dfrac{1160}8\right]\equiv 3[145]\equiv 435\ \ $ [All easy mental arithmetic]