# How can I solve $x^{5}\equiv 13 \pmod{18}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to solve the congruence of $ x^{5}\equiv 13 \pmod{18}$ and find whether it is solvable.

Actually I can solve $x^{k}\equiv \pmod{q}$ when $q$ is odd. But now it is composite, and I do not know how to apply the theorem. Can you help me?

Comment: @Moo A high-quality response.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem might be useful.

Comment: What does this have to do with solvable groups?

Comment: By the dupe: $\!\bmod \phi(18)=6\!:\ \dfrac{1}{\color{#c00}5}\equiv \dfrac{1}{-1}\equiv -1\,$ so raising $\,x^{\large \color{#c00}5}\equiv 13\,$ to power $\, \dfrac{1}{\color{#c00}5}\equiv-1\,$ yields $\,x\equiv \dfrac{1}{13}\equiv \dfrac{-35}{-5}\equiv 7\,$ by [inverse reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* By [Euler–Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $x^{6}\equiv 1 \bmod{18}$.

Comment: If $x$ and 18 are relatively prime.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, they must be if $x^{5}\equiv 13 \bmod{18}$.

Comment: But the theorem is available when q is odd prime. 18 is $3^{2} *2$. Gcd(17,12)=1.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got the point.