# How to prove that $50^{44}+30! \cdot44^{50}-24 $ is divisible by $31$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am struggling with this example. This is a new topic for me. I would really appreciate some hints to understand it. I need part a) and b) to conclude the excercise.

I was thinking about Fermat, Euler or Wilson theorems but I am not sure if it is correct, of course I can use properties of congruences in number theory.

Part a): show that $50^{44}+30! \cdot 44^{50}-24 $ is divisible by $31$
Part b) : Conclude that $ (50^{44}+30!\cdot 44^{50})^{\varphi(31)} \equiv 1 \pmod{ 31}$

Comment: Well, [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) seems like a good start.

Comment: Thank you. I agree because 31 is prime. In the right side  of the congruence $ -1 mod p$ and $p $ must be prime. And then I could find the residue equal to zero. Yes, that make sense.

Comment: Is $30!44^{50}$ meant as $30!\cdot 44^{50}$ ?

Comment: I guess you could easily solve part $b)$ after part $a)$ has been solved.

Comment: Yes, it is.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
50^{44} + 30! \cdot 44^{50} &\equiv 50^{44} - 44^{50} \pmod{31}, \text{ By Wilson's Theorem } \\
&\equiv 2^{44} \cdot 5^{88} - 2^{100}\cdot 11^{50} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{14}\cdot 5^{28} - 2^{10} \cdot 11^{20} \pmod{31}\text{, By Fermat's little Theorem } \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5 - (-3)^{10} \pmod{31}, \\
&\equiv 2^4 \cdot 5 - 3^{10} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^4  \cdot 5 - 3^{3\times 3}\cdot 3 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^4 \cdot 5 - (-4)^3 \cdot 3 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^4 (5+12) \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^4 (2^4+1) \pmod{31}
\\ &\equiv2^8  + 2^4 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^3 + 2^4 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 24 \pmod{31}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help to understand it in a better way. These are my first steps in modular aritmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handful of hints:

$50^{44} = 2^{44}5^{88}$

$44^{50} = 2^{100}11^{50}$

$2^5\equiv 1 \pmod{31}$

$5^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{31}$

$11^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{31}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice we can use Fermat's little theorem to reduce the exponents using [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242), based on these values:
$\  \color{#0a0}{2^5\equiv 1},\,$ $\, \color{#c00}{5^3\equiv 1},\,$ $\, \color{#90f}{11^3}\equiv 11(-3) \equiv \color{#90f}{-2},\,$ yielding

$$\begin{align} 
   \bmod 31\!:\quad\     & 50^{44}\!+30! \cdot 44^{50}\\[,2em] 
\equiv\ & 50^{14}\ \ \ \, -\,\ \ \ 44^{20}\qquad\ \ {\rm by}\ \ 30!\equiv -1\,\ {\rm by\ Wilson}\\[,2em]
\equiv\ &\color{#0a0}{2^{14}} \cdot \color{#c00}{5^{28}}-\color{#0a0}{2^{40}} \cdot \color{#90f}{11^{20}}\\[.3em]
\equiv\ &\ \ \ \ \ \frac{\color{#c00}{5}}{\color{#0a0}2}\,\ -\,\ \color{#0a0}1\cdot \color{#90f}{\frac{(-2)^{7}}{11} \ \ \ \text{by (*) below}}\\[.3em]
\equiv\ &\ \ \ \ \frac{\color{}{36}}{2}\ \ \ \ \ +\ \ \ \ \ \frac{\color{#90f}{2^{2}}}{11}\quad\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#0a0}{2^5\equiv 1}\\[.3em]
\equiv\ &\ \ \ \ 18\ \ +\ \ \frac{\color{}{4+62}}{11}\\
\equiv\ &\ \ \ \ 24
\end{align}\!\!\!$$

$\color{#90f}{\text{(*)}}\,$ we used $\ \color{#90f}{11^3 = -2}\ \, \smash{\overset{\Large x^{7}\!}\Longrightarrow}\ 11^{21} \equiv (-2)^7\!\Rightarrow \color{#90f}{11^{20}\equiv (-2)^7/11},\ $ then in the next two lines we [twiddle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) the fraction numerators by adding (or subtracting) small multiples of the modulus so to make the quotient *exact*.

Part b) is just FLT again.

Check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921015/modulus-of-fraction/921093#921093) to see how modular fractions work.

Comment: Good use of modular fractions (+1). For beginners it may help to highlight where you use the congruences in the 2nd line (e.g. associate them by color). Maybe that explains the downvote (or maybe it's a user who doesn't like modular fractions - alas there are many).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Thank you Guys. I really appreciate your help to understand it in a better way. These are my first steps in modular aritmetic. I ll do my best to understand it.

Comment: @Charlie and Neat Math. I added some color to help show the logic. Of course Neat is free to rvert or edit it to their preference.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks Bill. This is beautiful.

Comment: @NeatMath I'm sure you can improve it but that's all the spare time I have at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that

$\quad 2^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{31} \land 50 \equiv 19 \pmod{31} \land 44 \equiv 13 \pmod{31}$

we calculate (looking for 'presentation loop closure'),

$\quad 13^2 \equiv 2^1 \cdot 7^1 \pmod{31}$

$\quad 19^2 \equiv 2^2 \cdot 5^1 \pmod{31}$

$\quad 7^2 \equiv 2^1 \cdot 3^2 \pmod{31}$

$\quad 5^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{31}$

$\quad 3^5 \equiv 2^1 \cdot 13^1 \pmod{31}$

and write

\begin{align}
50^{44} + 30! \cdot 44^{50} &\equiv 19^{44} - 13^{50} \pmod{31}, \text{ By Wilson's Theorem } \\
&\equiv 2^{44} \cdot 5^{22} - 2^{25}\cdot 7^{25} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5^{1} -  2^{12} \cdot 3^{24} \cdot 7 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5^{1} -  2^{12} \cdot 2^{4} \cdot 13^{4} \cdot 3^4 \cdot 7 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5^{1} -  2^{12} \cdot 2^{4} \cdot 2^2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 7 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5^{1} -  2^{12} \cdot 2^{4} \cdot 2^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 7 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5^{1} -  2^{4}  \cdot 3^6 \cdot 7 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5^{1} -  2^{4}  \cdot 2^1 \cdot 13^1 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 5^{1} -  3 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 80 + 130 \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 24 \pmod{31}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help to understand it in a better way. These are my first steps in modular aritmetic.

Comment: What I am showing is not a better way, but a different way, using less theory with more of a elementary puzzle solving technique. But 'playing around' prepares you for understanding more advanced theory.

Comment: Several people have helped me out, so it is great to consider other perspectives that are very different from our own.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is *Community wiki* and takes a 'deep dive' into algorithmic solution design.

---

The 'elemental' exponent reducing identity in ${\displaystyle (\mathbb {Z} /31\mathbb {Z} )^{\times}}$ is

$\quad \large 2^1\cdot3^1\cdot5^1 \equiv 2^0\cdot3^0\cdot5^0 \cdot (-1) \pmod{31}$

and this can be expanded into a 'closed exponent reducing presentation system',

$\quad \large 2^4 \equiv 3^1\cdot5^1\cdot (-1) \pmod{31}$
$\quad \large 3^3 \equiv 2^2 \cdot (-1) \pmod{31}$
$\quad \large 5^2 \equiv 2^1\cdot3^1\cdot (-1) \pmod{31}$

**Part 1: Calculate $50^{44} \pmod{31}$**

Since

$\quad 50 \equiv 19 \pmod{31}$

$\quad 19 \equiv 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot (-1) \pmod{31}$

our 'not too smart' algorithm can be applied:

\begin{align}
50^{44}  &\equiv 19^{44}  \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{88} \cdot 3^{44} \cdot 5^0 \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{66} \cdot 5^{22} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{44} \cdot 3^{0} \cdot 5^{22} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{11} \cdot 5^{33} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{11} \cdot 5^{33} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{16} \cdot 3^{27} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{34} \cdot 3^{0} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{2} \cdot 3^{8} \cdot 5^{9} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{6} \cdot 3^{12} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{14} \cdot 3^{0} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{2} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5^{0} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{6} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{0} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{2} \cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 3^{0} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{2} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{1} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{0} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 18 \pmod{31}
\end{align}

**Part 2: Calculate $44^{50} \pmod{31}$**

Since

$\quad 44 \equiv 13 \pmod{31}$

and

$\quad 13 \equiv 2  \cdot 3^2 \cdot (-1)  \pmod{31}$

our 'not too smart' algorithm can be applied:

\begin{align}
44^{50}  &\equiv 13^{50}  \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{50} \cdot 3^{100} \cdot 5^0 \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{116} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{0} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{30} \cdot 5^{29} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{20} \cdot 3^{0} \cdot 5^{29} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{34} \cdot 3^{14} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{2} \cdot 3^{22} \cdot 5^{9} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{16} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{9} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5^{13} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{6} \cdot 3^{11} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{12} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{4} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{4} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{0} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{0} \cdot 3^{5} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 5^{1} \cdot (-1)^{0} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 2^{1} \cdot 3^{1} \cdot 5^{0} \cdot (-1)^{1} \pmod{31} \\
&\equiv 25 \pmod{31}
\end{align}

Comment: wow! interesting

Comment: Since I marked this as community wiki, if you make this your accepted answer nobody gets a reputation credit. So you might want to accept another answer... $\quad$ EXPERIMENT in PROGRESS - NOT TO BE USED IN MATH CLASS.

Comment: I didnt know it.  I find it useful as well.