# Calculate $142^{381}$ mod $773$ without a calculator .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Calculate $142^{381}$ mod $773$ without a calculator .

***Attempt:***

$$142^{(3\cdot 127)}=142^{381}$$
By try some number's
$$142^1\equiv142\pmod{773}$$
$$142^2\equiv66\pmod{773}$$
$$142^3\equiv96\pmod{773}$$

Lets check the gcd between $773,142$
$$\gcd(773,142)$$
$$773=142\cdot 5+63$$
$$142=63\cdot 2+16$$
$$63=16\cdot3+15$$
$$16=15\cdot 1+1$$
$$15=1\cdot15+0$$
$$\gcd(773,142)=1$$
How to find the answer from here ?

Comment: Your calculations are not correct.  $142^1 \equiv 142, 142^2\equiv 66, 142^3\equiv 96 \pmod{773}$

Comment: @RossMillikan Correct, I edited Thanks for the Correction.

Comment: Ast the end of your question you seem to be assuming $\;773\;$ is prime. Are you given this or have you already proved it?

Comment: @DonAntonio I just remember its prime number, I didn't prove yet. maybe i should delete this, Thanks

Comment: Clarification requested: what is the query's **context** (i.e. background)?  Is this a problem that you made up for yourself, or is this a problem that was assigned to you from a book/class/online-pdf?  My first step was to consult my number theory book to confirm that 773 is a prime.  Then, I factored $142 = 2 \times 71.$  Then, I considered exploring $(71)^2 \pmod{773}, (71)^3 \pmod{773}, \cdots$  In my opinion, my approach (which might not be the only approach) is **not feasible for me** without a calculator.

Comment: I could maybe do this by hand, but it would take me a week. Where did you get this question?

Comment: @TonyK Note that the OP did not outlaw using an **abacus**.

Comment: @user2661923 the problem from book without given the 773 is prime number.

Comment: Have you considered writing $381$ in binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$
x = 142^{381} \pmod{773}.
$$

Since $773$ is prime, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we have

$$
142^{772} = 1 \pmod{773}.
$$

Therefore, either

$$
142^{386} = 1 \pmod{773}
$$

or

$$
142^{386} = -1 \pmod{773}.
$$

We can distinguish the two cases using [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion). To that end, we need to compute the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)

$$
\left(\frac{142}{773}\right) = \left(\frac{71}{773}\right)\left(\frac{2}{773}\right)
$$

where we used the fact that Legendre symbol is a [completely multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function). Next, we use the [law of quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) to find

$$
\left(\frac{71}{773}\right) = \left(\frac{773}{71}\right) = \left(\frac{710 + 63}{71}\right) = \left(\frac{63}{71}\right)
$$

and similarly

$$
\left(\frac{63}{71}\right) = -\left(\frac{71}{63}\right) = -\left(\frac{8}{63}\right) = -\left(\frac{2}{63}\right)\left(\frac{2}{63}\right)\left(\frac{2}{63}\right).
$$

Substituting, we see that

$$
\left(\frac{142}{773}\right) = -\left(\frac{2}{63}\right)\left(\frac{2}{63}\right)\left(\frac{2}{63}\right)\left(\frac{2}{773}\right).
$$

Now, using the property known as the second supplement to the law of quadratic reciprocity

$$
\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}
$$

we find

$$
\left(\frac{2}{773}\right) = -1 \\
\left(\frac{2}{63}\right) = 1.
$$

Therefore,

$$
\left(\frac{142}{773}\right) = 1
$$

and so $142$ is a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue). Consequently,

$$
142^{386} = 1 \pmod{773}.
$$

Now, substituting $x$ and partial results listed in the question

$$
x \cdot 142^5 = 1 \pmod{773} \\
x \cdot 142^2 \cdot 142^3 = 1 \pmod{773} \\
x \cdot 66 \cdot 96 = 1 \pmod{773} \\
x \cdot 152 = 1 \pmod{773}.
$$

Thus, we see that $x$ is the multiplicative inverse of $152$ modulo $773$. We can find it by computing [Bézout's coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) using [Euler's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

$$
152 \cdot 178 + 773 \cdot (-35) = 1
$$

and so we see that

$$
178 \cdot 152 = 1 \pmod{773}.
$$

Therefore,

$$
x = 178 \pmod{773}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Easily we verify $\,773\,$ is prime. So $\!\bmod 773\!:\, $ if $\,142 \equiv a^2\,$ then $142^{386}\equiv a^{772}\equiv 1\,$ by Fermat, so $\,142^{381}\equiv 142^{386} 142^{-5}\equiv (142^{-1})^5.\,$ By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) $\,142^{-1}\equiv 7^2\,$ so $\,142\equiv 7^{-2}\,$ is indeed a square, so $\,142^{381}\equiv 49^5\equiv 49(82)^2 \equiv 49(-223)\equiv 178.\,$ Total time: a few minutes by hand.

Comment: We could also use quadratic reciprocity (Legendre symbol) to check that $142$ is a square $\bmod 773\ \ $

Comment: Did you do $0/773 \equiv 1/142 \equiv -5/63 \equiv 11/16 \equiv -49/(-1)$ (I was too lazy to include the frowns) or something else? Thanks.

Comment: @NeatMath Yes, that's exactly what we get using the [*fractional* extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242).

Answer (score 0):

The standard algorithmic solution to the "modular exponentiation" problem is to use "Square and Multiply Algorithm". Let me illustrate:

Suppose you need to calculate $$x^c \bmod n$$

Represent the exponent $c$ in binary:

$$c = \sum_{i=0}^{l-1} c_i 2^i$$ where $c_i$ is $0$ or $1$ and $0 \leq i \leq l-1$

Then use the following algorithm:

```
SAM (x, c, n){
z = 1

for i = l-1 downto 0 {
   z = z^2 mod n
   if (c_i = 1)
      z = zx mod n
   }

return z
}
```

Note that there are always $l$ squarings. The number of multiplications is equal to the number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $c$, which is an integer between $0$ and $l$. Thus the total number of modular multiplications is at least $l$ and at most $2l$

I used the above algorithm and found the value $178$

$x = 142, c = 381 = \{101111101\}, n = 773$

Here $l = 9$,

hence the number of squarings $= l = 9$ and

number of multiplications $ = $ number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $381 = 7$

```
SQUARE: 1
MULTIPLY: 142
SQUARE: 66
SQUARE: 491
MULTIPLY: 152
SQUARE: 687
MULTIPLY: 156
SQUARE: 373
MULTIPLY: 402
SQUARE: 47
MULTIPLY: 490
SQUARE: 470
MULTIPLY: 262
SQUARE: 620
SQUARE: 219
MULTIPLY: 178
===============
FINAL: 178
```