# Congruence system \begin{cases} 3x \equiv 4 \pmod{7}\\ 5x \equiv 9 \pmod{11} \end{cases}

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I've started to study number theory, I completely do not understand from my notes how to work this out. Could anyone show me with simple example how to solve this?

\begin{cases}
3x \equiv 4 \pmod{7}\\
5x \equiv 9 \pmod{11}
\end{cases}

Comment: Solve separately each congruence, then use the inverse isomorphism of the *Chinese remainder theorem* to determine the congruence class of $x\bmod 7\cdot 11$.

Comment: Apply the theorem in the linked dupe to scale the congruences to an equivalent system where the coefficients on $x$ are $\equiv 1,\,$ then apply CRT to solve that system.

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) $\,\bmod 7\!:\ x\equiv 4/3\equiv -3/3\equiv -1,\,$ and $\bmod 11\!:\ x\equiv 9/5\equiv 20/5\equiv 4.\,$ Next apply [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) to solve $\,x\equiv -1\pmod{7},\ x\equiv 4\pmod{11}\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3x\equiv 4 \mod 7$$

$$5\times 3x\equiv 4 \times 5 \mod 7$$

$$x\equiv 6 \mod 7$$

$x=7t+6, t\in Z$

$$5x\equiv 9 \mod 11$$

$$35t+30\equiv 9 \mod 11$$

$$2t\equiv 1 \mod 11$$

$$t\equiv 6 \mod 11$$

$t=11k+6, k\in Z$

$$x=77k+48, k\in Z $$