# what is the fastest way to solve this: 5x = 1 mod 7 with a formula

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I solve problems like this using trial and error especially when the given numbers are not that high.
But I am trying to build a calculator to solve this modulus problem:
5x = 1 mod 7

What's the formula to solve it without trial and error? Thanks.

Comment: One way is to note that $5^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  Or you can just use the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: $\bmod 7\!:\,\ x\equiv\dfrac{1}{5}\equiv \dfrac{-6}{-2}\equiv 3\ $ by [twiddling, or by modular division by 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242). See the linked dupes for many more methods.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $5x\equiv 1\mod 7$ is the same as asking $5x+7k=1$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

The inverse of $5$ in modulus $7$ is $3$, because $5\cdot 3=15$ and $15\equiv 1 \mod 7$. Then calculate
\begin{align*}
5x &\equiv 1 \mod 7\\
5x\cdot 3 &\equiv 3 \mod 7\\
15x&\equiv 3\mod 7\\
x&\equiv 3 \mod 7
\end{align*}
It follows that $x=7k+3$, so for example $x=3$ and in more general notation $5_{[7]}^{-1}=3$.

To find inverses for any $a \mod m$ you need to consider the equation $k\cdot x+m\cdot y=1$ and solve it with the extended euclidean algorithm. $x$ will be the inverse of $a$, i.e. $ax\equiv 1\mod m$.

You can always find a multiplicative inverse if $m$ is prime (like in your case, $7$ is prime so $1,\dots,6$ all have inverses), otherwise only some integers in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ will have inverses.

Answer (score -1):

We note that, for any integer $x$, we have
$$
5x \equiv 1 \mod 7 \tag{1}
$$
if and only if
$$
7 | (5x - 1),
$$
that is, there exists some integer $q$ for which
$$
5x - 1 = 7q,
$$
and thus
$$
5x - 7q = 1. \tag{2}
$$

As $\gcd (5, -7) = 1$, so we can express this $\gcd$ as a linear combination of $5$ and $-7$ as
$$
1 = 5(3) - 7(2).
$$
Thus one solution of (1) is $x \equiv 3 \mod 7$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).