# How to handle modulus when there is division operation in the expression?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am asked to print all numbers modulus of $1000000007$.

My expression is $x*(1+f(x))/2$

For cases when x is even it is simple as i can do (x/2) first, then do:

$ ((x/2)*(1+f'(x)) modulus  1000000007 $

f'(x) is $f(x) modulus 1000000007$, f(x) is an exprssion wherein it has multiplications and additions already performed under modulus 1000000007 .

So for cases when `x` is odd if $((1+f'(x))modulus 1000000007)/2$ gives wrong answer.

Comment: Hint: for odd $a,n$ we have $\bmod n\!: a/2 \equiv (a+n)/2,\,$ and $a+n$ is even so the division is *exact* - see  modular "**division by** $2$" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque I still can't follow , can you explain with an example, you can consider me a novice in modular arithmetics.

Comment: Lets say x=1000000011. As the division is perfect, So for (1+f(x)) to be divisible by two f(x) has to be odd. Now I dont know the actual value of f(x) since it has been taken modulus 1000000007 several times, so what comes out of f(x)%1000000007 is even, now what should I do? –

Comment: The link which you marked as dup, might be talking about same sunject matter but talks of a different function. So I dont know how to relate to solve my scenario.

Comment: Let $\,a = x(1+f(x))\bmod n\,$ then apply my first comment. See the linked dupe for specific examples. The point is that we can always choose an *even*  number congruent to $a$, which makes it trivial to divide by $2,\,$ as explained in the linked post.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) more general post on solving linear congruences. Here you are solving $\,2X\equiv a\pmod{n}\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque all these study material that you are linking are too overwhelming for a beginner to grasp at once. All I got is we need to calculate inverse in such cases to convert a division to multiplication. and in my case inverse of `1/2` seems to be `(1+p)/2` ie (1+1000000007)/2=500000004

Comment: Yes, that's the special case: $\,a=1,\ n = p\,$ odd,  in my first comment. It is essential to learn basic modular arithmetic to understand matters like this - see any good textbook on elementary number theory.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that division by 2 is the same as multiplication by 1/2 and that 1/2 is just any number with the property that if you multiply that number by 2, you get 1.

So... if you can find any number $y$ such that $2y = 1 \mod 1000000007$ you can think about this number $y$ as 'being' (or playing the role of) 1/2 in the world modulo 1000000007.

And once you have $y$ you can think about division by 2 as multiplication by $y$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Can you explain with an example lets say x=1000000011. As the division is perfect, So for (1+f(x)) to be divisible by two f(x) has to be odd. Now I dont know the actual value of f(x)  since it has been taken modulus 1000000007 several times, so what comes out of f(x)%1000000007 is even, now what should I do?

Comment: here is an easier example. Suppose we take the modulus to be 9 instead of your huge number. The principle is the same, see also the linked quesion. You know that 2 * 5 = 10. But modulo 9 that means 2 * 5 = 1. So 5 serves as something that can play the role of 1/2 in this world. Now if we want to divide 7 by 2 modulo 9 what we can do is multiply 7 by 1/2, so by 5. We know that 7 * 5 = 35 = 8 mod 9 so my claim is that 7/2 = 8 mod 9. To check if that is true, all we need to do is see if 8 * 2 = 7 mod 9 and indeed this is the case!

Comment: Similarly the 'abstract quantity' $f(x)/2 \mod 9$ must be the same as $5 f(x) \mod 9$

Comment: I shouldn't say I have fully managed to grasp what you said, but whatever example you gave coupled with my experimetation suggests for my case I have to replace `(1/2)` with `(1000000007+1)/2`. So my equation becomes `x∗(1+f(x))*500000004`...  generally speaking under `mod p`, `(p+1)/2` is the inverse of `(1/2)`. Tell me if I am correct?

Comment: Yes, in as far I understand the problem you are working on, that is correct!

Comment: Ehm except one thing in the formulation of the general case. `(p + 1)/2` is the inverse of `2` in the `mod p` world, not the inverse of `(1/2)`. I think we mean the same thing. Since `(1/2)` is the inverse of `2` in the real world, `(p+1)/2` can be thought of as 'being' (or 'playing the role of')  `1/2` in the `mod p` world