# How to solve $x \bmod y = z$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm working on a cryptography programming puzzle. I've worked out that the basic formula to generate a character is $$(x \cdot 2^i)\bmod 67 = character.$$

In order to decode, I need to work out what are the possible values for x, with $1 \leq x \leq 67$.

Here are some example equations and their solutions from WolframAlpha:

$2x \bmod 67 = 1 \implies x = 67n +34$

$4x \bmod 67 = 20\implies x = 67n + 5$

$8x \bmod 67 = 29\implies x = 67n + 12$

I want to understand what steps WolframAlpha is doing: How do I take the forms on the left and put them in the forms on the right?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133194/reverse-modulus-operator) post on StackOverflow was helpful, but I didn't understand it well enough to generalize the approach. I studied some modular arithmetic, couldn't find the part that would help me here.

Comment: Do you ask for general $i$, or are you trying to solve for every $i$ as individual cases? This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: Since $~2 \times 34 = 68 \equiv 1 \pmod{67},~$ you have that the first equation is solved by $~x \equiv 34 \pmod{67}.~$  Similarly, since $~4 \times 5 \equiv 20 \pmod{67},~$ you have that the second equation is solved by $~x \equiv 5 \pmod{67}.$

Comment: Re previous comment, note that for any positive integer $(i)$, that $2^i$ is relatively prime to $(67)$.  Therefore, for any of the corresponding equations, there will always be exactly one unique value of $x$ (within a modulus of $67$) that satisfies the corresponding equation.

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242), if $\,0\le b< n\,$ then $\ ax\bmod n = b\!\iff\! ax\equiv b\pmod{\! n}.\,$ The linked dupes explain how to solve such linear congruences (generally, as here, it is usually proves easiest to convert mod *operations* into equivalent but more (arithmetically) convenient congruences).

Comment: This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) shows how to easily do **modular division by $2$**. Iterating that you can divide by any power of $2$ so you can compute your $\,x \equiv c/2^i\pmod{67}\ \ $

Comment: @insipidintegrator, I don't understand your question (are you looking for general i?). I'm looking for what generalized methods I can use to take the formulas in the second section from the left side to the right side. I'll take a look at the wiki article.

Comment: I'm afraid that the formula at the top was taken as a red herring. I wanted to show the encoding formula. For decoding, *i* is known, the the second part of the question is the important part, how to go from left to right.

Comment: For your linked SO example, a simple proof is, given $\,0\le b < m,$  $$\begin{align} (a+x)\bmod m &\,=\, b\\[.2em]
\color{#c00}\iff\qquad\quad\ \ \  a+x&\,\equiv\, b\ \ \ \ \ \,\pmod{\! m}\\[.2em]
\iff\qquad\qquad\quad\ \, x&\,\equiv\, b-a\!\!\pmod{\! m}\\[.2em]
\color{#0a0}\iff\qquad x\bmod m&\,\equiv\, (b-a)\bmod m\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: The $\rm\color{#c00}{first\!\! \iff}$ arrow converts from mod operator to congruence form using the first displayed equivalence [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242), the second solves the congruence by adding $-a$ to both sides using the [Congruence Sum Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), and the $\rm\color{#0a0}{last\ arrow}$ converts from congruence back to mod operators using the prior-linked equivalence between the two.